# Oracle Apex: How to put a dynamic value in filter

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

is it possible to add a dynamic value on filter.
I'm trying to save a report with a filter using the current user:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to this problem is to include the variable as a column in your query and then filter on that column.
Example:
Your select would be something like

```
SELECT 
  your_value1,
  CASE WHEN created_by = :APP_USER THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_current_user
FROM 
  your_table
```

If you then set a filter on is_current_user you'll only get the rows where created_by = :APP_USER.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is possible; though, I don't know how. Whichever option I tried:

- `:APP_USER`
- `&APP_USER.`
- `v('APP_USER')`
- created a page item whose source is `:APP_USER` and base filter on that item

nothing worked. Apex applies single quotes around those *expressions* and - therefore - treats them as strings, e.g. `':APP_USER'`.

However, what you might do **in this particular case** is to edit the query itself and add `WHERE` condition:

```
where blocked_by = :APP_USER
```

That would certainly work.